# mysql wont select from table using foreign (hindi/devanagari) characters

Tags: php, mysql, select, foreign-keys, collation

I looked around and couldn't find an answer.

I want to select a word from a mysql table that is a Hindi dictionary to get the definition.

There are no errors, it just doesn't select it. I tested it with English letters and it worked. I tried setting the lex column to VARCHAR, TEXT, BLOB with utf8_bin, utf_general_ci, utf_unicode_ci.

Here is the code:

```
$lex = 'सुकून';
$get_def = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM hindi_dictionary WHERE lex = '$lex'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_def)) {
  $def = $row['def'];
  }
echo $def;
```

Comment: I tried "SELECT * FROM hindi_dictionary" and echoed all the 'lex'. It echoes a '?' for each keystroke required to type the word. सुकून requires 5 keystrokes. Therefore it echoed '?????' - 5 questions marks.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was put this in there:

```
mysqli_query($con, "set names 'utf8'");
```